# How to debug a php page when it need recieve http request?

Tags: php, xdebug, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I am using zend studio to develop php, and installed xdebug on apache2. Now I can debug the php page by right-click the page and debug-as cli.

If I need to debug the registration form page that receives the user input information. How can I debug this page and watch the received variable, e.g. user_name. I can do it in servlet when I use java.

Answer (score 0):

how about a few debug "echos" ?

```
echo var_dump($variable_that_i_want_to_know_more_of);
```